# Unexpected Snackbar+Alert behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, material-ui

Why is this throwing an error:

```
import Snackbar from "@mui/material/Snackbar";
import MuiAlert from "@mui/material/Alert";
const Alert = ({children}) => <MuiAlert>{children}</MuiAlert>

<Snackbar open>
    <Alert>test</Alert>
</Snackbar>
```

(but this is not?)

```
import Snackbar from "@mui/material/Snackbar";
import MuiAlert from "@mui/material/Alert";

<Snackbar open>
    <MuiAlert>test</MuiAlert>
</Snackbar>
```

In my understanding, they should both work the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I needed to pass the `ref` using `React.forwardRef` to the Alert:

```
import Snackbar from "@mui/material/Snackbar";
import MuiAlert from "@mui/material/Alert";
const Alert = React.forwardRef(({children}, ref) => <MuiAlert ref={ref}>{children}</MuiAlert>)

<Snackbar open>
    <Alert>test</Alert>
</Snackbar>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're using single line component syntax, you don't need to use `return` keyword for getting back the component. Just `=>` is enough:

```
import Snackbar from "@mui/material/Snackbar";
import MuiAlert from "@mui/material/Alert";
const Alert = ({children}) => <MuiAlert>{children}</MuiAlert>

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Snackbar open>
        <Alert>test</Alert>
      </Snackbar>
    </>
  );
}
```